# Integración de Login Facebook Android

Tags: android-studio, facebook-api

Buenas tardes

Estoy por implementar el modo de incio de sesion por facebook login, solo que tengo una duda, tengo que tener mi aplicacion publicada en el playstore?

Lo pregunto por que me pide escribir mi `packagename`

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

No es necesario que tu aplicación se encuentre en el playstore, el package name de tu aplicacion lo puedes encontrar el archivo build.gradle esta como applicationId[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Es el [package name](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html), que es definido como un id de la aplicación, no necesitas tener publicada tu aplicación pero cuando sea firmada para la tienda playstore el [package name](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html) debe ser ùnico.

Lo puedes encontrar dentro de tu `build.gradle` (valor de `applicationId`):

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        ...
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

o dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml` (propiedad `package`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started